# Referencing of an element of an array after emptying the array

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and try to understand some core concepts.

I created an array and assigned it to the variable `fullNames`. Then I declared another variable (`fullName`) and assigned the first (and only) element of `fullNames` array to that variable.

As I checked, if I modify the first element (which is an object) of `fullNames` array the value is also modified for element assigned to the `fullName` variable, which basically means that element wasn't simply copied to `fullName` variable and that `fullName` simply points to the first element (object) in `fullNames` array. Right?

However, if then I remove all elements from an array initially assigned to `fullNames` variable, the `fullName` variable to which the first element was assigned still logs this same element.

So, what happens in that case? Why `firstName` still points to some object if all elements were removed from an array prior I log `firstName` to console?

```
let fullNames = [{ name: "Name", surname: "Surname" }];
let fullName = fullNames[0];

fullNames.length = 0;

console.log(fullNames); // displays []
console.log(fullName); // displays { name: "Name", surname: "Surname" }
```

Comment: Objects in JS are reference types. What you are saying is `var a = {x:1}, b = a;`. When you do like `a = null;` then the reference chain gets broken and `b` remains as originally referenced (instantiated) `{x:1}`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the length of the array to zero clears out the array but does not edit the content. So all references still exist for values that would have been included in the array.

The rules are different for [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) though, which may be the behavior you are expecting.

```js
var string = "abc";
var obj = {
  test: 123
};
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var bigArr = [];

bigArr.push(string, obj, arr);

console.log(bigArr);

bigArr.length = 0;

console.log(bigArr);
console.log(string, obj, arr);

var obj2 = obj;

console.log(obj, obj2);
delete obj2.test;

console.log(obj, obj2);
```